# Index and Analyze Xml Data in Graylog

Tags: graylog2, graylog

Is it possible to import and index XML data with Graylog?
I know that it's built over ES, which only indexes fields of JSON objects.
Is there a way to do it out of the box or I need to manually convert XML to JSON?